# Access javascript variables from calling scope

Tags: javascript, string, scope

I am trying to define a function which can access variables which are in the scope of the function that is calling it.

( I am attempting to build a string formatter that is prettier than "a" + b, and more terse than String.format("a{0}",b).  So I can get SF("a{b}"), and I don't know if it is possible )

so

```
function magic(str) {
    return parentScope[str]; // or return eval( str );
    // or something like that
}

function call() {
    var a = 1;
    alert( magic( "a" ) );
}
call();
```

would alert "1".

currently I can do this by having the function return code to be eval'd, but it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: There used to be an "arguments.caller" and I think an "arguments.callee.caller" to get at the parent, but implementation is browser-dependent and more and more out-of-favor. I think even arguments.callee could end up being deprecated. Best to just stay away from all that.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your 'magic' function into the call function:

```
function call() {
    function magic(str) {
        return a; 
    }

    var a = 1;
    alert( magic() );
}
call();
```

This mechanism behind the scenes is called *closures* and which are very powerful concept. Just think of an AJAX request where the callback function still can access the local variables of the calling function.

**UPDATE**

I misunderstood your question. The thing you actually want to build is impossible to implement in JavaScript because the is no way to access the caller's scope.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is my string formatting function. Not as concise as you may want it, but still very usable.

```
String.prototype.arg = function()
{
    result = this;

    // This depends on mootools, a normal for loop would do the job, too  
    $A(arguments).each((function(arg) 
    {
        result = result.replace("%", arg);
    }).bind(this));

    return result;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
"%-% %".arg(1,2).arg(3)
```

and receive

```
"1-2 3"
```

Comment: I don't think this helps given the context of the question - he's looking to pull arbitrary variable names out of a string based on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is impossible to reach out and grab an arbitrary variable from a function in javascript. From an object yes, but not from an executing method.

I can't think of any function method (apply, call, otherwise) which helps you here: frankly I think you're trying too hard for a marginal benefit over the normal string.format, er... format.